# How to access the file pointer of each blocks of a file from the $MFT file in NTFS?

Tags: c++, windows, file, ntfs-mft

I am working on file virtualization and versioning project. For that, I need to access the logical blocks of file contents directly without copying into memory. Anyone could you help me with code snippets that works on my 64 bit windows?

I tried the following code to access the MFT file. But it responds like 'Access denied' even though I ran with administrator privileges.

```
#include<windows.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<winioctl.h>
// Format the Win32 system error code to string
void ErrorMessage(DWORD dwCode);
int wmain(int argc, WCHAR **argv){
    HANDLE hVolume;
    WCHAR lpDrive[] = L"\\\\.\\C:";
    PNTFS_VOLUME_DATA_BUFFER ntfsVolData = {0};
    BOOL bDioControl = FALSE;
    DWORD dwWritten = 0;

    hVolume = CreateFile(lpDrive, GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE,NULL,OPEN_EXISTING,0,NULL);

    if(hVolume == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE){
        wprintf(L"CreateFile() failed!\n");
        ErrorMessage(GetLastError());
        if(CloseHandle(hVolume) != 0)
            wprintf(L"hVolume handle was closed successfully!\n");
        else{
            wprintf(L"Failed to close hVolume handle!\n");
            ErrorMessage(GetLastError());
            }
        }
        else
            wprintf(L"CreateFile() is pretty fine!\n");
            ntfsVolData = (PNTFS_VOLUME_DATA_BUFFER)malloc(sizeof(NTFS_VOLUME_DATA_BUFFER)+sizeof(NTFS_EXTENDED_VOLUME_DATA));

        bDioControl = DeviceIoControl(hVolume, FSCTL_GET_NTFS_VOLUME_DATA, NULL, 0, ntfsVolData,sizeof(NTFS_VOLUME_DATA_BUFFER)+sizeof(NTFS_EXTENDED_VOLUME_DATA), &dwWritten, NULL);
        if(bDioControl == 0){
            wprintf(L"DeviceIoControl() failed!\n");
            ErrorMessage(GetLastError());
            if(CloseHandle(hVolume) != 0)
                wprintf(L"hVolume handle was closed successfully!\n");
            else{
                wprintf(L"Failed to close hVolume handle!\n");
                ErrorMessage(GetLastError());
                }

        }


    getchar();
}

void ErrorMessage(DWORD dwCode){
    DWORD dwErrCode = dwCode;
    DWORD dwNumChar;
    LPWSTR szErrString = NULL;  // will be allocated and filled by FormatMessage
    dwNumChar = FormatMessage( FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER |FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM, 0, dwErrCode, 0,     (LPWSTR)&szErrString, 0,0 );               // since getting message from system tables
    if(dwNumChar == 0)wprintf(L"FormatMessage() failed, error %u\n", GetLastError());//else//wprintf(L"FormatMessage() should be fine!\n");
    wprintf(L"Error code %u:\n  %s\n", dwErrCode, szErrString) ;// This buffer used by FormatMessage()
    if(LocalFree(szErrString) != NULL)
    wprintf(L"Failed to free up the buffer, error %u\n", GetLastError());//else//wprintf(L"Buffer has been freed\n");
    }
```

```
CreateFile() failed!
Error code 5:
  Access is denied.

hVolume handle was closed successfully!
DeviceIoControl() failed!
Error code 6:
  The handle is invalid.

hVolume handle was closed successfully!
```

Thank you

Comment: *without copying into memory* - this is how ?

Answer (score 0):

Admin privileges aren't enough. What you need to do is request backup and restore privileges for your process. MSDN has [sample code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/seccrypto/setting-the-backup-and-restore-privileges). Keep in mind that you probably need both `SE_BACKUP_NAME` and `SE_RESTORE_NAME`.

The process is a bit cumbersome:

1. Use `OpenProcessToken` on your process with `TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES`
2. Use `LookupPrivilegeValue` to get the privilege based on the string constants (one for `SE_BACKUP_NAME`, one for `SE_RESTORE_NAME`)
3. Use `AdjustTokenPrivileges` to acquire the backup and restore privileges

If you do this properly, the rest of your code should work. To actually enumerate the MFT, you'll want to use the `FSCTL_ENUM_USN_DATA` variant of `DeviceIOControl`.

Comment: I tried with your solution but it denies the access again even the privilege got modified successfully .